# Confused about bounty questions

Tags: support, bounties

I answered this question which had a bounty (100 or 150 I think) but now it doesn't?

[ASP.NET custom templated datalist throws argument out of range (index) on button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463028/asp-net-custom-templated-datalist-throws-argument-out-of-range-index-on-button)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the bounty period probably expired without the owner of the question accepting an answer.

Comment: ah, that's pretty lame. thanks for the info Kris!

Comment: @Ian that's probably it. Has happened to me in the past (both as answerer and as an asker.) Losing a bounty is the one situation where a sympathy upvote is totally justified IMO, so +1 from me :)

Comment: Bitter sweet that I now have the +3 which would have earnt me the bounty. Hey ho - it's the swings and roundabout's that's stackoverflow :-)

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 0):

There are occasions where the auto-accept doesn't kick in as I'd expect; for example, there was a bounty that expired on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653812/grouping-geographical-shapes/2667805#2667805) a couple of hours ago, but no bounty was awarded, and no answer has been auto-accepted.